# Trouble with INDIRECT formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

This is my formula:

```
=IF(ActualsThrough<F$5,SUMIF('209Budget'!$F:$F,'209ActBud'!$C7,'209Budget'!I:I),-IFERROR(OFFSET('Month TB'!$D$1,MATCH($C7&+"-"&+$C$2,'Month TB'!$B:$B,0)-1,MATCH(F$5,'Month TB'!$D$1:$O$1,0)-1),0))
```

I would like to have the formula use an indirect dynamic reference for 209Budget and 209ActBud.

The idea is that I can enter "209" in an reference cell and all the formulas will update.  When I copy the sheet to a new tab, I can then change the reference cell to "210", and all the formulas will update.

The problem I am having is trying to make the ranges be relative.  The indirect formula requires the range reference to be in "".  This causes the formula to be static rather than dynamic, which makes me unable to copy the formula across rows and columns.

Comment: for some reason the formula didn't copy through.

Comment: "=IF(ActualsThrough<F$5,SUMIF('209Budget'!$F:$F,'209ActBud'!$C7,'209Budget'!I:I),-IFERROR(OFFSET('Month TB'!$D$1,MATCH($C7&+"-"&+$C$2,'Month TB'!$B:$B,0)-1,MATCH(F$5,'Month TB'!$D$1:$O$1,0)-1),0))"

Comment: please edit your question instead of putting details into comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the cell with 209 is in A1 of the current sheet, you can build a reference with Indirect like this:

```
=Indirect("'"&A1&"Budget'!$F:$F")
```

If your sheet name does not have spaces, you don't need to wrap it in single quotes, so,

```
=Indirect(A1&"Budget!$F:$F")
```

Applied to the ranges that reference sheet 209, the whole bundle would look like

```
=IF(ActualsThrough<F$5,SUMIF(indirect(A1&"Budget!$F:$F"),indirect(A1&"ActBud!$C7"),indirect(A1&"Budget!I:I")),-IFERROR(OFFSET('Month TB'!$D$1,MATCH($C7&+"-"&+$C$2,'Month TB'!$B:$B,0)-1,MATCH(F$5,'Month TB'!$D$1:$O$1,0)-1),0))
```

Edit after comment: If you need the column reference in the Indirect to be relative, so it updates when the formula is copied to the right, you can use the Cell() function.

Instead of

```
...indirect(A1&"Budget!$F:$F")...
```

use

```
...indirect(A1&"Budget!"&cell("address",F:F))...
```

Comment: Hi Teylyn (great name by the way).  Thank you for your answer.  Here is where I am having trouble.  When the column that needs to be relative is enclosed in quotations  >>>indirect(A1&"Budget!I:I")<<< the column reference inessence becomes static.  When I copy the formula from column I to column J, the formula still references column I.

Comment: no problem. I added a suggestion to my answer. If that solves your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour].

Comment: great idea, but perhaps I am using the formula wrong.  When I use ....&cell("address",F:F) the result is $F:$1.  But I think I can find a way to work with that.

Comment: Well, the question has been closed, so this is my last post. `=SUM(INDIRECT($A$1&"Budget!" &CELL("address",F1)&":"&CELL("address",F100)))`